# Can you tell from sound if it’s a fuel starvation problem?

Tags: fuel-system

Car was cutting out and mechanic told me ‘it sounds like a fuel starvation issue’.  In other words he was able to get a lead from sound.

Does this work and how would I be able to based on sound identify if it’s likely a fuel starvation issue?

Comment: Just spend 10 years or so listening to engines that are in good or poor condition and for those in poor condition know what the faults are.

Comment: Alternatively, use computer AI. There are now jet engines in service where a computer continuously monitors all the engine vibration sensors, compares any changes with a database of the previous maintenance history for the entire engine fleet, and if required sends a message to the maintenance engineers at the destination airport telling them what to check out.

Comment: @alephzero probably out of the op’s price range, but also used on wind turbines.

Comment: Maybe fuel pump and filter are clogged?